How do I punctuate a sentence with multiple questions when each of them are in quotes?
This is the sentence I am referring to:

Instead of asking “Will I get the  job?”, consider asking, “What can I do to align myself with my career  aspirations?”

Is this correct? I am specifically referring to the comma that follows "job?" If this isn't correct, can you help me construct this sentence properly? Thank you.

Some allow double punctuation; others don't. There isn't a punctuation czar. But isthe comma really necessary after the first question ... isn't the offsetting sufficient without one, the question mark doing dual duty? The comma before the (second) quote is also considered optional by many nowadays (some choose between comma, colon and zero punctuation on merit).

See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9343/what-is-the-best-way-to-punctuate-a-list-of-questions-in-a-declarative-sentence https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468468/what-is-the-proper-way-to-quote-multiple-questions-within-one-sentence-without-u
